# How does the ground electrode in a three pole gas discharge tube work?

Tags: power-supply, surge-protection

I'm developing a surge protection circuit with a three pole gas discharge tube (I used [this one.](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/bourns-inc/2026-35-C2LF/1220301))

[image]

When I apply the AC power source (220V 50Hz) sometimes the fuses were blown but rarely. I know it's because the DC breakdown voltage of my GDT is quite low, but when I connect the ground pole of the GDT to the ground of my power supply system, the fuses always blew and I don't why. How should I use the ground pole of a three pole GDT?

Comment: When you say "fuses blown" do you mean circuit breakers pop, or do you mean actual fuses. Frequently, circuit breakers are equipped with ground fault current interruption, gfci. If that is the case here, the gfci is activated by current through the ground electrode in your tube.

Comment: You should use it period. You should also be unambiguous which device you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The ground (earth) lead is to prevent over-voltage from line *and* from neutral to ground. Even the neutral can have a voltage difference to earth if there's a nearby lightning strike, or wiring error.

The circuit protection gas discharge tube (GDT) you've chosen has a **DC** breakdown voltage of 350 V. Your ciruits connects to an AC line, and the **peak** voltage of a smooth sine wave is ~1.414 times the root mean square voltage (RMS) of 220 VAC, or ~311 V. This is perilously close to the breakdown voltage of the GDT, which sparks over, as intended, *shorting* the input (well, technically, they operate in the arc region of perhaps 20 V until the fuse blows, or something else is destroyed).

This is expected behavior in gas discharge tubes -- they're *excellent* for rapidly shorting a high over-voltage, but are subject to random operation due to electromagnetic fields or even cosmic radiation. The 300V [MOV varistors are a bit more forgiving](https://www.circuitstoday.com/metal-oxide-varistor-mov), in that they don't clamp the voltage as tightly as the MOV, so they degrade slowly and are less likely to blow the fuse unless there is sustained over-voltage.

You might search that catalog for a device with a bit more headroom, perhaps 420 VDC spark-over. And most *definitely connect the earth lead* to provide protection from either side of the line to earth. Of course, in the Americas, connect that lead to ground, instead. ;-)